# Why do I get the same graphic for a join of two relations and a join of three relations?

Tags: alloy

Below I create three sets: Name, Address, and Host. The addr field maps Name to Address. The host field maps Address to Host.

```
sig Name {
    addr: Address
}

sig Address {
    host: Host
}

sig Host {}
```

Here I ask the Alloy Analyzer to create an instance for the join of two relations: addr and host.

```
run {one addr.host} for 1
```

This is the graphic that is generated:

[image]

Next, I ask the Alloy Analyzer to create an instance for the join of three relations: addr, a ternary relation of identical atoms in each tuple, and host.

```
run {one addr.{a, b, c: univ | a = b and b = c}.host} for 1
```

Surprisingly, the graphic generated is identical to the one shown above. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visualizer shows an instance by giving values for each of the named relations and sets. Your second example still has only two named relations in it. If you want to see the value of a relation that is given just as an expression, you'll need to name it, eg like this:

```
run {some r: univ -> univ -> univ | 
  r = {a, b, c: univ | a = b and b = c} and 
  one addr.r.host} for 1
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize this. Thank you (again) Daniel!